# Thymeleaf - use javascript as th:if condition

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to use a javascript condition as a 'th:if' condition.
In specific i want to show a html element only when a scrollbar is existing in another element and tryed like this:

```
<div th:if="'javascript:document.getElementById(\'my-element\').scrollHeight>document.getElementById(\'my-element\').clientHeight'"></div>
```

Is something like this posible? Or should I do this in the '$(document).ready' function?

Comment: You can embed evaluated Thymeleaf expressions into JavaScript using Thymeleaf's `th:inline`; but you can't embed evaluated JavaScript expressions into Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf is processed on the server before its results are sent to the browser. It has no knowledge of how the JavaScript expression might be evaluated (to `true` or `false` in your case). So, unless I have misunderstood your question, `th:inline` won't help you. I would recommend going with your `$(document).ready` approach.

Comment: OK thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

As @andrewjames rightly commented above, you cant embed evaluated JavaScript expressions into Thymeleaf. You might want to change your approach.
Try something like this to use javascript and thymeleaf together -

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    ...
        //your code
    ...
</script>
```

Read more about how to use thymeleaf and javascript together in official documentation - 
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining

Comment: Can you clarify how this might be used to address the OP's specific question? I don't think he needs to embed a Thymeleaf expression into JavaScript - I think it's the other way round.

Comment: Yes sorry, how to use javascript in thymeleaf is clear to me. I want to know if it is possible to use a javascript expression inside a 'th:if' condition.

Comment: No you cant with the approach you're using, in simple words thymeleaf is processed at server side and the javascript approach you're using runs at client-side i.e on your browser.